# add signature or image on PDF using drag and drop android (get x and y coordinates )

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, pdfbox, ontouchlistener

I am using Pdfbox `https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android` to add signature(image) on pdf i want to add signature using drag and drop i have implemented some code using  touch listener please see and help me i am not getting exact x and y coordinates to add it in pdfbox code from  touch listener and i also try drag and drop code`https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_drag_and_drop.htm` but it won't help. when i test the app and drop the signature(image) on pdf the result pdf won't get the signature on right position. please help your little brother and guide me if anything wrong with the code

**Here is the code of Pdfbox**

```
 private void createPdfTwo(File file,float x,float y) {
        try {
          PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);          
           PDPage page = doc.getPages().get(0);  
          // StoredPath is the path where it gonna be saved
            PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(StoredPath,doc);
            PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page,true,false);
        // here is the x,y which i am getting from touch listener
            contents.drawImage(pdImage, x, y,150,150);
            contents.close();
            doc.save(storedPath);
            doc.close();
            pdfView.fromFile(new File(storedPath)).load();
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**here is the touch listener code**

```
 @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener()
{
    return (view, event) -> {

        final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                        view.getLayoutParams();

                xDelta = x - lParams.leftMargin;
                yDelta = y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          // here is the code where magic should happen                                 
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams qParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                        view.getLayoutParams();
             float   xD = x - qParams.leftMargin;
              float  yD = y - qParams.topMargin;
          // this method will calling the create pdf (file is defined global)
                createPdfTwo(file,xD,yD);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Signature Drop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = x - xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = y - yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
        }
        mainLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    };
}
```

}

Comment: What is the coordinate system of the Android view? The PDF coordinates usually have 1 unit equaling a pt, i.e. 1/72in. Furthermore, x coordinates increase rightwards, y coordinates increase upwards, and the origin *often* is in the lower left corner but can actually be anywhere. And `contents.drawImage` uses the given coordinates for the lower left corner of the image. If anything here does not coincide with your Android View, you'll have to transform the coordinates before calling `createPdfTwo`.

Comment: i am getting x and y in pixels. so i have to convert them in points(inches)? if yes please provide me a formula for it

Comment: Hey Sayed Talha, I'm also looking the same concept to implement in my project,  It seems you posted this long time back, I hope you made good progress on this, please help me how did you calculate the coordinates. Please update here

Comment: I did some progress. I converted the PDF into Image with PdfBox library then place it into ImageView and set height and width to wrap content. Then added touch listener on that image after that I used the event.getX() and event.getY() method to get x,y coordinates. Then I used the Canvas to draw the signature image on pdf image with x,y coordinates then I converted the image again into pdf with itext. If you want code then tell me. 
I am still working on multiple pages of pdf.
And there is a problem that I can't resize the ImageView

Comment: Hey Sayed Talha, Thanks for reply. After spending a lot of time on this problem, I have decided the same to do. So please share code, it will be a good help from to make my things fast.

Comment: where should i send you the code?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry, I didn't mention how to share code with me.
please mail code in .zip to ssuresh1016@gmail.com

Comment: https://github.com/sayedtalha124/SignatureOnPdf.git here is the repository. If you find any difficulty let me know at urtalha0@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks for you kindness Sayed Talha. I'm doing this task for 2 weeks T_T. Wish all the best for you.